# Process Builder -updating GrandParent fields

Tags: process-builder

I've 3 objects A(GrandParent), B(Parent), C(child).

Now I want to update a field of GrantParent(A) using field of child C, based on some conditions through process builder.

But tricky part is : I want to consider only those child C records which are linked to 'most recent' Parent record, to update GrandParent A.

For e.g, Say A has record A1. And A1 has two associated records, Child B1 and B2 and B2 is latest.

I want to consider Child C records associated with B2(Not B1) to update A1.
Similary if later on, B3(new record) comes up ,then only child records associated with B3 should be updating A1.

Is this possible without invoking APEX throughProcess builder ?

I'm not able to find criteria(to select 'most recent' B's record) while creating step of process builder, that uses object C to update A

Comment: You could also use an autolaunched flow triggered by the process builder to do this.

Comment: Sounds to me like this is past the point where you should be considering using triggers/Apex rather than process builder.

Comment: I've done conditional grandparent updates from child using proc builder, but it required using 2 separate proc builders. One proc builder on child to update a flag on parent when appropriate, and then the flag on parent triggers another proc builder to update grandparent. Of course, this can get messy, and proc builder lives within the confines of governor limits, so doing stuff like this can get dicey. I tend to agree that at this point your most advanced option would be apex.

Answer (score 0):

If these are Master-Detail (such that you can do a rollup summary), perhaps:

1) On object A you could have a rollup summary containing the maximum datetime (last modified? or last created?) of all its B-children.

2) On the Process Builder for C, you only execute the update if the B-parent's datetime equals the A-grandparent's roll-up value.

Caveat: if two B-siblings have the exact same datetime in that field, then you might get concurrency trouble.

If these are lookups rather than M-D, the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool would help.